# Is there an option for 2-rows header in kendo-ui-angular2 grid?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

The [docs](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/) doesn't specify this, and all I've encounter are some example of the [jquery-version of kendo ui grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders)

I would like the table to look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
|               |            header 2          | 
-    header 1   --------------------------------
|               | sub header   |   sub header  |
------------------------------------------------
| data rows goes here...                       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently its not supported. It is in the plans for the next release though.

Comment: Thanks! You mean the final release planned to May 2017? I saw the [roadmap page](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/) , but is there a place I can see specific planned feature release dates?

Comment: The roadmap page is the one that should be monitored. And yes - most probably the multi column headers will be available in May.

Comment: Thank you very much @knikolov !